# Sharepoint Incoming email setup?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to change the default FQDN "exmaple@sharepoint.Domain.local" to something like example@sharepoint.com?
I have installed the SMTP feature on the sharepoint server and when In IIS 6.0 it displays "exmaple@sharepoint.Domain.local"
Would I change this under incoming email settings in CA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to configure.

1. Setup an entry to direct @sharepoint.com to the IP of the SP server you are running IIS 6.0 SMTP feature.
2. On the SP server with the SMTP, open IIS 6.0 and on the Domains section, add a new domain alias with sharepoint.com. I can't recall if this is absolutely necessary, but I believe so.
3. In CA, under Configure Incoming Email settings, you will add sharepoint.com to the Incoming email server display address.

References:

Configure SharePoint 2010 Incoming Email
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx#section2

IIS 6.0 SMTP configuration
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e2156172-7118-4ff2-9a6a-1b7dd52580fa.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Could you expand on the First step please. I have no problems understanding the other two. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a scenario:
SharePoint Server with smtp: 192.168.1.2
Firewall appliance that handles NAT for your network - public ip: 1.2.3.4
You configure a MX record with your DNS hosting company for the domain name you want that points to 1.2.3.4
Your firewall appliance routes mail traffic on port 25 to 192.168.1.2

A better explaination might be here:  http://www.petri.co.il/configure_mx_records_for_incoming_smtp_email_traffic.htm